# Remover um objeto dentro de um array salvo no LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, localstorage

Eu salvei um array no localstorage, só que dentro desse array tem vários objetos, como eu faço pra acessar e remover um objeto especifico dentro do array?

```
const Storage = {
    get() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devfinaces:transactions")) || []
    },
    set(transactions) {
        localStorage.setItem("devfinaces:transactions",
        JSON.stringify(transactions))
    }
}

const Transaction = {
    all: Storage.get()
}
```

Exemplo de Transação:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  amount: 1500,
  date: 2021-09-23
},
{
  id: 2,
  amount: 1000,
  date: 2020-04-13
}]
```

ai eu quero apagar a transação com id 1 e adicionar uma nova transação dentro do array (todo o array esta salvo no LocalStorage), como faço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaproveitei as funções que você já tinha criado (get e set) usando o "this"

Criei uma função chamado "remove" que recebe um parâmetro chamado id.

Primeiro vamos obter a lista atual:

```
let transactions = this.get();
```

Depois vamos filtrar essa lista e remover o que não queremos:

```
let newTransactions = transactions.filter(function(transaction) { 
            return transaction.id !== id;  
        });
```

Agora setamos o novo valor filtrado

```
this.set(newTransactions);
```

E retornamos a lista atualizada (isso não é obrigatório)

```
return this.get();
```

Ficaria assim:

```
const Storage = {
    get() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devfinaces:transactions")) || []
    },
    set(transactions) {
        localStorage.setItem("devfinaces:transactions",
        JSON.stringify(transactions))
    },
    remove(id){
        let transactions = this.get();
        let newTransactions = transactions.filter(function(transaction) { 
            return transaction.id !== id;  
        });
        this.set(newTransactions);
        return this.get();
    }
}
```

Tem outras maneiras de fazer, mas essa deve funcionar.